# How to make particles fall and land into predetermined shapes (like text)?

Tags: animation, particles, rigid-body-simulation

I'm wondering how to approach this problem. I just watched a video on how to get particles to "morph" shapes, but what I'm looking for is more natural-looking... My specific idea is to have pieces of candy corn fall into the letters BOO! I can figure out the particle system emitter, and I can get the particles to fall, but I'm scratching my head on how to get them to naturally fall into the BOO shape.

Are there any good resources for this kind of simulation?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you need to give your letters a Physics > Collision, but maybe share your file so that we see where is the problem more precisely

Comment: I should clarify: I'm not trying to get them to fall into a physical object... the idea is that the particles fall onto a flat plane, but the particle trajectory/path's end position is going to spell out a word. I'm still working on my blender file at the moment. I'll try a couple things and then post my .blend file. Thanks!

Comment: so maybe create some letters and make them invisible?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.... I added my .blend file to my original post, in case you wanted to poke around.

Comment: something like that except you make the letters invisible in render: https://zupimages.net/up/20/43/ofmm.gif

Comment: ben's solution seems to be a nice addition to my idea, put all you candies inside invisible letters then make them move up (depends on where they are supposed to come from though)

Comment: Could you explain more what is "natural looking"? Is it about the fall or the final shape (or other)?

Comment: Or https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9EKV.gif ?

Comment: So I guess what I was aiming for was this: imagine you have a handful of candy corn and you simply toss it onto a table or similar surface. I wanted to the candy to naturally slide a little bit on the table, and have their ending position be in the shape of the text. Does that make sense?

Comment: So, two steps: they fall on the table then from the table they move to form the text?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct... I want them to fall onto the table while sliding/bouncing/colliding towards the shape of the text.

Answer (score 6):

You could do it backwards.  Have a mesh (set to not be visible in the render itself) define the shape for the particles to end up in, have this mesh start with a lot of particles only inside its volume, and then animate them all 'falling' randomly upwards under an appropriate force.  Then reverse the animation, either externally or via baking it and reversing the order of keyframes.

Whether this looks good or very faked will depend on the look you're going for and the shapes of your targets.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, you've given me an idea for this year's Christmas card!  :)

Answer (score 5):

Start the animation with a huge number of particles and make them fall onto the plane.

Bake them and transform the particles into real objects with keyframes.

Select all the particles and remove from selection (You can use the C shortcut to activate the circle selection) those in the places you want to save (where the letters should be drawn) and delete the others.

Answer (score 4):

You can create invisible letters and make your candies fall into. For the letters, in the *Properties panel > Physics > Rigid Body > Collisions > Shape*, choose *Mesh*:

[image]

If you don't want candies to fall out of the letter, once they have fell into the letter, you can select them all at frame X, go in the header menu > *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes*, then, as suggested by Ben, give them a new *Rigid Body*, but this time make them move up with a *Gravity* of -1 in the *Scene* settings, or with some *Force Field*, then invert the render so that they fall down into the letter.

Comment: Very nice! Absolutely better than my solution!

Answer (score 3):

**Fake physics with keyed particles**

[image]

Keyed particles allows to drive in time the movement of the particles along several objects.

The driver has itself a particle system in which settings we can define the sequence of other objects the particles will go through.

The objects of this sequence have their own particle system (with eventually their own parameters).

Here I've placed:

- a cube to start with,
- a plane that will fake the point where particles should fall to the table,
- another shape that defines the surface of the table the particles fall on
- the text object

The driver particle system has the following settings:

[image]

where:

- Physics is set to *keyed*
- *Use timing* is on
- In *relations* are added the object sequence
- And for each of them we indicate the *time* (in frames) at which the particle will be on it and the *duration* it will stay on it (these times are relative to its birth)

[The documentation is here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/particles/emitter/physics/keyed.html).

[image]

Comment: Applied Remesh modifier with 0.01 used on letters helps to even distribution (especially on letter B :) BTW particles are quite crossing each other, I'm wondering if that can be avoid somehow? Thanks :) Great answer.

Comment: @vklidu, thanks for this comment. I was not able to make rigid body work when using keyed. So, yes, they overlap. Don't know if there is a solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Rigid Body

[image]

[image]

Convert particles to Rigid Body (with add-on or if you don't mind how they appear on scene just apply particle modifier).  Similar to moonboots's answer, but ...

- Use one plane collider as floor to let candies fall on a desk.
- Then use another collision object with letters shape extruded conicaly upward, and animate location on Z axis.

[image]

[image]

[image]